# Copyright regulations and piping

Tags: copyright

As I understand, the copyright regulations help non-proliferation of duplication and repetition but nothing to do with profiteering. But can they do justice about "piping" at speeds beyond average human capabilities?

"Piping" is just transferring input field entries at a mobile touch screen or terminal to unknown terminals or devices, through unknown browser or device, in the normal internet context.

If the 'fair use' involves unfair third party financial transactions, does the copyright holder has any legal right to claim a share of the profit?

My concern is about deliberate human interference while creation of a material in the present electronic storage, publication and distribution media.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I do not get what you are asking.  What is "piping" in this context?

Comment: "Piping" is just transferring input field entries at a mobile touch screen or terminal  to unknown terminals or devices, through unknown browser or device, in the normal internet context.

Comment: For me, at least, your explanation did not help clarify but added to confusion.  Please explain what you are asking in detail.

Comment: Are you asking if something like Chromecast, piping content from one device to another, is form of copyright infringement?

Comment: Maybe your question would benefit from a concrete, specific example.

Answer (score 1):

If copyrighted material is copied without a license, that's copyright infringement (with some exceptions for fair use in the USA). Whether anyone reads the copied material is irrelevant. You can be sued for it.

Back in the day there were people making illegal copies of video games that fell into the category "hunters and gatherers". They never played any of these games, their entertainment was finding the games and making copies. Some had hundreds of games, never paid for any, never played any, just stored away. That was copyright infringement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141499/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-copyright-regulations-and-piping).